# how to remove the spaces from the end of nsstring

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I want to remove the spaces from the end of nsstring in objective c

for example @"Ali        "  be @"Ali"

and so on ,

any suggestion please

best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSString* aliNoTrailingOrLeadingSpaces = 
    [@"Ali " stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: This removes whitespace in beginning and end.. Works great!

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *trimmedString = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                                  [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

This will also remove the whitespace from the start...